# How to disable "use password for" functionality in Chrome in forms

Tags: angularjs, passwords

I have an AngularJS app, and in Chrome, this "Use password for" functionality is giving me a headache.
After logging in, I go the newUserForm which is $mdDialog that opens and has a form in it to create new users. When I put focus on the username field, it shows me a list of usernames; the same happens with the password field, only that asking me to use passwords from other users, which is obviously not an option.
How do I turn this off? I cannot believe chrome team thought this was helpful.

I'm using angular 1.6 and material.

Comment: please share your code here

Comment: Well, the code is rather extense, I don't think I can put a fiddle up and running, but I can post fragments: <input type="password" id="password" ng-model="newUser.password" name="password" ng-value="password" ng-blur="validaPassNew(newUser.password)" is the problematic field.
The form is just a regular html form.

Autocomplete="off" is useless, I read chrome made it un-disable-able. It is my opinion that this functionality goes way beyond autocomplete, is a certainly annoying and dangerous tool.